# How to create div with different class on button click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I was creating a html that would create a div and copy the things in input to that div with a button click.

Like this:

HTML

```
<input type="text">
<button>Copy</button>
<p></p>
```

Script

```
$('button').click(function() {
   var div = document.createElement('div');
   $('p').append(div);
   $('div').html($('input').val());
});
```

At it worked perfectly

And then i added class to it.

It looks like this:

```
$('button').click(function() {
   var div = document.createElement('div');
   div.className = "Someclass";
   $('p').append(div);
   $('div').html($('input').val());
});
```

It worked fine as well. But when i click the button it copies the text to all the div's Instead of a single one

**How can i create a button that creates different div with different class and which copies text from `<input>` to the newly created div**

I found on net that i can use the `i++` thing in javascript for different class.

But that code is not working properly. Please tell me what is the mistake here.

My code looks like this:

```
$('button').click(function() {
   var i = 0;
   var div = document.createElement('div');
   div.className = "Someclass" + i++;
   $('p').append(div);
   $('div').html($('input').val());
});
```

Comment: Actually you define `i` on every click, so the `className` will always be `Someclass0`. Furthermore, the `$('div')` selector will catch all the div's in your document and will overwrite all of their content

Comment: How can i solve it??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. take out `i` from click event
2. select new div with its corresponding class name `.Someclass[i]`

change your code like this:

```
var i = 0;
$('button').click(function() {

    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.className = "Someclass" + i;
    $('p').append(div);
    $('.Someclass' + i).html($('input').val());
    i++;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

```
var clickCount = 0;

$('button').click(function() {
  var html = $('input').val();
  var classname = 'someclass' + clickCount++;
  $('<div>').addClass(classname).html(html).appendTo('p');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather use .addClass jquery method:

```
$( "div name" ).addClass( "yourClass" );
```

Answer (score 1):

You are appending html to all `div` present.Do this add content to it before appending

```js
var  i=0;
$('button').click(function() {
   var div = document.createElement('div');
   div.className = "Someclass" + i++;
   $(div).html($('input').val());
  $('p').append($(div));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text">
<button>Copy</button>
<p></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Its doing that because you have this line

```
 $('div').html($('input').val());
```

You can change it to

```
 $('p div').html($+'input').val());
```

Answer (score 1):

You should give the precise class name like 'Someclass'+i with " i " the last index of the class you added.

```
$('button').click(function() {
   var i = 0;
   var div = document.createElement('div');
   div.className = "Someclass" + i++;
   $('p').append(div);
   $('Someclass'+i).html($('input').val());
});
```

Your code looks like it will add only one div by click and that div will be given the value of input.